Why does the Torah ignore the Philistine nation?
The books of the Prophets and Kings highlight the ongoing conflict between the Judeans and the Philistines. However, the Torah shows no awareness of the Philistine nation (people) besides not letting the Israelites pass through their land in fear of witnessing war.
EDIT: Please note, I ask about the Philistines as a nation that resides within the borders of the Holy Land that God promises to His people, not the mention of several kings that Abraham and Isaac met.
They are not mentioned in the list of the eight nations to be obliterated, although they don't seem to be less idolatrous or evil. Their land, however, does constitute a part of the "Whole Eretz Israel" description "from the Nile to the Euphrates".
What are possible explanations for this phenomenon?

"Their land, however, does constitute a part of the 'Whole Eretz Israel' description 'from the Nile to the Euphrates'." So does the Arameans'. It doesn't seem like the seven nations were intended to describe everyone in that expansive boundary.

"no awareness of the Philistine nation" Yitzchak has extensive dealing with the Philistine nation (this weeks parsha, genesis 26)

The Plishtim only really start becoming an ongoing conflict well into sefer shoftim hundreds of years after moshe. Plausibly, in moshe's days they hadn't expanded as much to the northwest and weren't a concern.

The seven nations are all descendants of Canaan. The Philistines are not. So no reason for them to be included.

Those people called Philistines are actually the remnant of the Kaftorim, They were a part of the Minoan civilization and had a trade settlement in the northeastern province of Mitzrayim along the coast of the Mediterranean. When their homeland was obliterated with the eruption of Thera, part of their remnant attempted to take up permanent settlement. This was part of the reason that Avram was called to leave the place where he was born and return to the land bequeathed to his ancestor Shem Ben Noach.

@Meir of what relevance is being a descendant of some particular person?

@DoubleAA Because that person was cursed, while the ancestors of the Philistines were not.

@Meir Neither were the ancestors of the Prizi (at least in pshat). And that is insufficient reason to distinguish, for many of Canaan's children aren't mentioned either (eg. Arak, Sin, Arvad, Tzemer). The curse isn't that we should kill them all.

@DoubleAA In pshat you have ואחר נפצו משפחות הכנעני, meaning that other nations of the 7, such as the Perizi, are indeed descendants of Canaan who just got a new name. The other children of Canaan didn't live in Eretz Yisrael, so they're not included.

@Meir I guess we have different definitions of pshat because what you just said simply isn't what those words mean.

@Meir So your saying the curse of Canaan is only on descendants of his that live in a certain place? Odd for Noach not to mention that in his curse.

@DoubleAA All right, let's translate the posuk for you word by word. ואחר, "and later," נפצו, "they were dispersed," משפחות, "the families," הכנעני, "the Canaanites." Meaning that there were the original Canaanite nations listed there, which afterwards further dispersed into nations and sub-nations that got different names. Rashi says precisely that: מאלה, "from these," נפצו, "dispersed," משפחות "families," הרבה "many."

And, @DoubleAA, the curse was עבד עבדים יהיה לאחיו. A subset of that is that if those עבדים fail to live up to their role, and are occupying a land that is supposed to belong to their masters, then they are going to be evicted in whatever way is needed, up to and including לא תחיה כל נשמה. If they're not עבד עבדים, or if they are but are occupying other lands, then others can and will deal with that as they see fit, but they're not receiving a commandment from Hashem to do so. Pretty straightforward, really.

@Meir Id say it's one convoluted theory with no evidence in the Chumash, not at all straightforward. But sure, you are welcome to put it out there.

@DoubleAA Sorry for not being understood, I edited the question.

@AlBerko huh? I don't get your edit. It's the same people

@DoubleAA Just something to ponder regarding your comment above about “killing them all”. See Shemot 14:30. Who was “dead on the edge of the sea”? Was that referring to all the Egyptian people?

Both Avraham and Yitzchak extensively dealt with people living in Pilishtia and made peace agreements with them in Beer Sheva (Bereishis 21:32, Bereshis 26:28-29). Additional details about who were the Pilishtim are suggested by Talmud Chulin 60b and R' Guggenheimer in the answer regarding the wells, that Pelishtim comprized of 2 different people the Avvim who came from Teiman by the time of Avraham and displaced the Canaanim, while Pelishtim who were the Sea People from Kaftor (Cyprus) and Crete who came by the Time of Yehoshua. Possibly, because the Pelishtim (Avvim and Kaftorim) had their own lands in Teiman, the Sea Islands, and other Coastal areas, they never had a full claim to Eretz Yisrael. On the other hand, the Canaanim did have such a claim, as Avraham and Yaakov were buying land from them. (Many thanks to @Yø-cRo for very helpful sources).
Regardless, the midrash Bereshis Rabba 54:4 gives a possible reason, why the tensions between the Jews and Pelishtim arose only beginning with the era of Shoftim, once it became incumbent for the Jews to take over Eretz Israel and why they were able to conquer them only at the time of David:

“Abraham took flocks and cattle, and gave them to Avimelekh, and the two of them established a covenant” (Genesis 21:27).
“Abraham set aside seven ewes of the flock by themselves” (Genesis 21:28).
“Avimelekh said to Abraham: What are these seven ewes that you have placed by themselves?” (Genesis 21:29).
“Abraham took flocks and cattle, and gave them to Avimelekh…Avimelekh said to Abraham: What are these seven ewes?” – the Holy One blessed be He said to him [Abraham]: ‘You gave seven ewes against My wishes, by your life, I will delay the rejoicing of your descendants for seven generations.’
‘You gave him seven ewes against My wishes, by your life, they [the Philistines] will correspondingly kill seven righteous men of your descendants.’ They are: Ḥofni and Pinḥas, Samson, and Saul and his three sons.
‘You gave him seven ewes against My wishes, they [the Philistines] will correspondingly destroy seven Sanctuaries of your descendants.’ These are: The Tent of Meeting, Gilgal, Nov, Givon, Shilo, and the two eternal Temples [in Jerusalem].
‘You gave him seven ewes against My wishes, My Ark will correspondingly circulate in the Philistine countryside for seven months.’ That is what is written: “He sent His strength into captivity, [and His splendor into the hand of the foe]” (Psalms 78:61) – this refers to the Ark of the Covenant. And it is written: “The Ark of the Lord was in the Philistine countryside seven months” (I Samuel 6:1). “And His splendor into the hand of the foe” – this refers to the priestly vestments, as it says: “You shall make holy vestments for Aaron…and for splendor” (Exodus 28:2).

Perhaps, the added words in brackets [the Philistines] implies that the Philistines cooperated with Assyria, Bavel, and other invaders against Jewish people. In particular, an earlier midrash Bereshis Rabba 54:2 explains the point about derekh Eretz Pelishtim:

Rabbi Yosei bar Ḥanina said: It is written: “My enemies are mighty with life” (Psalms 38:20). What was granted to Abraham after seven generations was granted to Avimelekh after three. Why? “God did not guide them via the land of the Philistines” (Exodus 13:17), because his [Avimelekh’s] grandson was still alive [at that time]. (Moses was the seventh generation from Abraham, and he was not allowed to conquer the lands of the Philistines because Avimelekh’s third-generation descendant was still alive then. This shows the extraordinary longevity of Avimelekh’s line.)


The gemara (Chullin 60b) clearly states that the Kaphtorim conquered the original Plishtim (the Avvim) before Yehoshua conquered the land, so that they would not be beholden to Avraham’s oath.

@Yø-cRo thank you for the source. Before the statement about the oath, Gemara says that Avvim still were strong among the Pelishtim (the sixth power). It explains why Yehoshua could start fighting with Pelishtim, however the midrash explains why only David was able to conquer them.

Thank you. Maybe I didn't pronounce it clearly enough. I stressed "nation", not single kings. God doesn't command on dealing with them at all in the Torah while in the following books, we see constant interaction and tension.

@AlBerko the nations in those days entrusted the external affairs with their kings. It might be that the code of law required such an action. Everything that Avraham or Yitzchak did was reported to king Avimelekh. Even beginning with the Yehoshua's time, it was the Philistine king who directed raids into the land of Israel or settlements, just like it was Jewish Sanhedrin and later the king who determined defense policy. Also, it seems that David succeded to beat Philistines as he brought 7 of their generals including Uriah.

@YDJ Targum Onkelos and Rashi both state that the covenant between Yitzchak and Avimelech was just an extension of the covenant of Avraham.

@YDJ The fact that this Avimelech was king of Gerar should indicate that he was of the Gerarite (AKA Avvite) Plishtim. Also, Avimelech is a Semitic title, not likely to be employed by a Greek, non-Canaanite individual.

@Yø-cRo it is not always the case. The Greek Pilishtim also adopted semitic language upon arrival, see about the Ashdodite language https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/146127/36610

@YDJ Over a period of centuries, not within fifty years of their arrival.

@Yø-cRo maybe, however, immigrants usually loose the language quickly. Look at the sabras in Israel, how many of them speak Polish, Hungarian, or Russian? Usually one generation. Yiddish died in the US in one generation.

@Yø-cRo thank you so much!!! I edited the answer there https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/146088/36610 and going to do so here.
